# Mysql add variable value to result set inside stored procedure instead subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

This is subquery working fine with required result, now I am writing a stored procedure for the same results.

I want to use in stored procedure logic as

- Declare variables
- Set them
- use in queries

Query:

```
SELECT payloadstr,
       starttime
FROM   pa
WHERE  conid IN (SELECT conid
                 FROM   con
                 WHERE  lognid IN (SELECT id
                                   FROM   log
                                   WHERE  phyid IN (SELECT id
                                                    FROM   phyid
                                                    WHERE  mac = 9729)));
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You cannot call a stored procedure from a query so I don't see that the stored procedure can replace a sub query - you should expand your question a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
BEGIN
    SET @macid = 9729; -- Take input from stored procedure

    SET @phyid_id = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`id`) FROM `phyid` WHERE `mac` = @macid);
    SET @log_id = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`id`) FROM `log` WHERE `phyid` IN(@phyid_id));
    SET @con_conid = (SELECT `conid` FROM `con` WHERE `lognid` IN(@log_id));

    SELECT `str`, `time` FROM `pa` WHERE `conid` IN(@con_conid);
END
```

Comment: thanks, this gives me much support to find my exact data.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a suggetion for code  (the answer to the spefic issue is already in the question comment by P.Salmon)

Instead of a collection of nested  IN (subselect )
you could use some inner join

```
select pa.str, pa.time 
from pa 
INNER JOIN con ON con.lognid = pa.conid 
INNER JOIN log ON con.lognid = log.id 
INNER JOIN phyid ON log.phyid = phyid.id AND  mac =9729
```

Comment: yes, I use inner join,
just for understanding for the procedure I share subquery.